# Check If All Tiles Are Connected

Tags: javascript, algorithm

[image]

Hi! I have an interesting problem.

I have drawn in a HTML canvas a series of hexagons (ignore the dots)

For each hexagon I have it's x and y coordinates of their center, that's how I identify them.

I store the hexagons in an array called hexagons where I store Hexagons

```
    function Hexagon()
    {
        this.shape
        this.x
        this.y
    }
```

I have a function that returns an object with all the adjacent hexagons of a given hexagon

```
function get_adjacent_hexagons(hexagon)
{
    var x = hexagon.x
    var y = hexagon.y
    var adjacents = []
    for(var i=0; i<editor_hexagons.length; i++)
    {
        if(editor_hexagons[i].x === x && editor_hexagons[i].y == y - (2*s))
        {
            adjacents.push(editor_hexagons[i])
        }
        if(editor_hexagons[i].x === x && editor_hexagons[i].y == y + (2*s))
        {
            adjacents.push(editor_hexagons[i])  
        }
        if(editor_hexagons[i].x === x - (s*1.5) && editor_hexagons[i].y == y - s)
        {
            adjacents.push(editor_hexagons[i])  
        }
        if(editor_hexagons[i].x === x - (s*1.5) && editor_hexagons[i].y == y + s)
        {
            adjacents.push(editor_hexagons[i])  
        }
        if(editor_hexagons[i].x === x + (s*1.5) && editor_hexagons[i].y == y - s)
        {
            adjacents.push(editor_hexagons[i])  
        }
        if(editor_hexagons[i].x === x + (s*1.5) && editor_hexagons[i].y == y + s)
        {
            adjacents.push(editor_hexagons[i])  
        }
    }
    return adjacents
}
```

Given this information, is it possible to make an algorithm to check if all the hexagons are connected

That is if there is no hexagon or group of hexagons on their own?

For example in the picture provided they are all connected.

----- EDIT -----

This seems to be working

```
function check_connection()
{
    visited = []
    visit_hexagon(hexagons[0])
}

function visit_hexagon(hexagon)
{
    var not_visited = true
    for(var i=0; i<visited.length; i++)
    {
        if(visited[i] === hexagon)
        {
            not_visited = false
            break
        }
    }
    if(not_visited)
    {
        visited.push(hexagon)
        var adjacents = get_adjacent_hexagons(hexagon)
        for(var i=0; i<adjacents.length; i++)
        {
            visit_hexagon(adjacents[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. However, given your `get_adjacent_hexagons` implementation, I doubt it will be efficient.

Comment: What's the difference between the `hexagons` array and that `editor_hexagons` variable? Why is `adjacents` a global variable?

Comment: @Bergi you're right, by editor_hexagons I meant hexagons, let me edit that.

Comment: @Bergi adjacents is not global, I just fixed that

Comment: Again, `visited` should not be global; make it local and `visit_hexagon` a local function in `check_connection`. Instead of the `not_visited` loop, just use [`indexOf`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/1048572). Also, this hardly works, as `get_adjacent_hexagons` returns an object but you iterate it as if  `adjacents` was an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by organizing your nodes (hexagons) into a graph structure where each node has a reference to the other nodes it is connected to. Mark all nodes as "unvisited". Start at any node and perform a [breadth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) first search marking each node you find as "visited". If after this there are any nodes that are not marked "visited" then your graph is not completely connected.

Comment: @madprops I think your get_adjacent_hexagons is probably not working correctly.

Comment: but they are, I think. Check this picture http://i.imgur.com/t17KrRc.png I inserted those console.logs when I get the adjacents, printing each adjacent id. For some reason it doesn't visit 30

Comment: @madprops I think it's because `adjacents` is global. You're replacing the list of adjacents in the recursive call.

Comment: No problem. Also you could make this a lot more efficient by pre populating the list of adjacents once and storing that in each hexagon object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since you can find the adjacent hexagons, you can create a graph of all the hexagons on the map. Then, you can simply run a breadth first search starting from a single node in the graph, and then check if all the nodes have been found after the end of the search. See more detailed at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Computational_aspects